# Otree / Python - Sequential group matching based on player attribute

Tags: python, grouping, otree

I am currently working on an oTree online experiment with 5 treatment groups. Within each treatment players will be assigned to groups of 2 players.

Therefore, the participants of my experiment click on the link and are assigned to 1 of 5 treatment groups `(['TG1', 'TG2', 'TG3', 'TG4', 'CG'])` via the following function

```
[def creating_session(self):
    for player in self.get_players():
        player.experimental_group = random.choice(\['TG1', 'TG2', 'TG3', 'TG4', 'CG'\])
        print('set player.experimental_group to', player.experimental_group)][1]
```

In the next step, I would like to match players with the same experimental_group attribute into groups of 2 players. And I would like this matching to happen sequentially in the order of them joining the experiment to reduce wait time.

How can I perform this group matching based on the player.experimental_group attribute?

I attach the following image to make things clearer: I would like to match P1 with P3 since they are both 'TG3' and P2 with P4 and so forth.
[image]